# Font size of cvlistdoubleitem

Tags: fontsize, moderncv

I'm preparing my resume and I used this structure:

```
\cventry{YEAR}{Title}{}{}{}{Description}
```

In order to get some space, I have to use

```
\cvlistdoubleitem{Skill 1}{Skill 2}
```

I'm trying to have the same font size in `Skill 1` & `Skill 2` as the `Description` field in `\cventry`.

So I have to reduce the font size in `\cvlistdoubleitem` and at this point I'm totally blocked.

Comment: Please, make a full MWE, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *description* field in `\cvitem` is set using `\small` across all the [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) styles. So, a quick fix is to update `\cvlistdoubleitem` to pass its mandatory arguments with `\small` prepended:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\oldcvlistdoubleitem\cvlistdoubleitem
\renewcommand*{\cvlistdoubleitem}[3][.5ex]{\oldcvlistdoubleitem[#1]{\small #2}{\small #3}}
```

This is not optimal since `moderncv` uses [`ifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) to test whether supplied arguments are empty or not, which fails when one passes a switch like `\small`. However, if you're not using both items in `\cvlistdoubleitem`, then use `\cvlistitem` and also add this

```
\LetLtxMacro\oldcvlistitem\cvlistitem
\renewcommand*{\cvlistitem}[2][.5ex]{\oldcvlistitem[#1]{\small #2}}
```

Comment: I tried \small like this: \cvlistdoubleitem{\small Test 1}{\small Text 2}. It works! without using the LetLtxMacro. Should I keep it like this or not ?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN: Your choice. Adding `\small` *will* work, but you'll have to add it to every instance. Using `\LetLtxMacro` updates `\cvlistdoubleitem` to *always` insert `\small`.